# Read value of localStorage on body load or document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, local-storage

This is using jQuery UI 1.12.1 and jQuery 3.1.1. To start with, I'm using this function to store the state of two tabs in localStorage in `currentIdx`:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
 active: localStorage.getItem("currentIdx"),
 activate: function(event, ui) {
      localStorage.setItem("currentIdx", $(this).tabs('option', 'active'));
  }
});
```

It stores the active tab (either 1 or 0) and shows that tab on a page reload ot after a browser restart. It fires on tab change, and I can see the value of `currentIdx` change in the console.

I'm also using this function

```
function checkStorage(){
    if (localStorage.getItem("currentIdx") == "1") {
$('body').addClass('yes');  
    } else {
$('body').addClass('no');   
    };
}
```

to check the value of `currentIdx` and change the body class according to the value. I have two classes in CSS, `body.yes` and `body.no`. And I use this body tag to fire `checkStorage`:

`<body onload="checkStorage()">`

and on an initial page load I see either `<body onload="checkStorage()" class="not">` or `<body onload="checkStorage()" class="yes">` in dev tools and the body CSS changes.

The two body classes work on an initial page load or a new window or tab, so `currentIdx` is being read.

But the body class doesn't change on a tab change; it does does change *after* I refresh the page after a tab change.

So how do I get the body class to be read all the time? I tried `$(document).ready(function()` but that doesn't help.

**Edit**

This works without having to use the `onload="checkStorage()` in `<body>`; might not be real pretty, but it works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    checkStorage();

        $("#tabs").tabs({
        active: localStorage.getItem("currentIdx"),
        activate: function(event, ui) {
        localStorage.setItem("currentIdx", $(this).tabs('option', 'active'));

    checkStorage();

    }
});

function checkStorage(){

        if (localStorage.getItem("currentIdx") == "1") {
        $('body').toggleClass('sucks').addClass('yes');  
        } else {
        $('body').removeClass('not').addClass('no');   
        };
        }

});
```

Comment: `So how do I get the body class to be read all the time?` What do you mean by all the time?

Comment: The body class doesn't change on a tab change; it does does change after I refresh the page after a tab change.

Comment: You need to change the body class in your `activate` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
  active: localStorage.getItem("currentIdx"),
  activate: function(event, ui) {
    localStorage.setItem("currentIdx", $(this).tabs('option', 'active'));
    checkStorage();
  }
});

function checkStorage(){
  if (localStorage.getItem("currentIdx") == "1") {
    $('body').removeClass('no').addClass('yes');  
  } else {
    $('body').removeClass('yes').addClass('no');   
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, that works. But only for one tab change; after that, the CSS doesn't change again

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Can you `console.log($(this).tabs('option', 'active'), typeof $(this).tabs('option', 'active'));` within activate?

Comment: It shows a column, and each click adds a line: 1 number, 0 number, 1 number, etc. So the click function is working.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I've updated the answer, please have a look. You need to toggle the class between `yes` & `no`

Comment: Ah, that works. Thanks! I figured out how to get rid of the `onload="checkStorage()` in the body tag by using `checkStorage();` again. Might not be real pretty, but it works.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch If you are satisfied then please accept the answer.